# what is the best possible ways to share map data among multiple spring mvc application?

Tags: spring-mvc, caching

I don't have sound knowledge of caching. my requirement is that i want to **access a map data** that should be sharable among multiple spring mvc application.Please let me know best possible solution.

note[map data will be heavy i.e big in size]

Comment: see https://hazelcast.com/

Comment: How to use hazzle cast in spring mvc project? getting error .how to do HazelcastConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

To share a big map, you can use a couchdb and share reference between applications.

Following are the reasons suggested:

1. If you are planning on transferring big maps the mapping at source and destination is going to cost you transactions and computing.

   2. Instead a caching dB which stores only the map will help you reduce burden.